# How to print out a set of variables in a for loop

Tags: arduino

I'm writing a program that logs and prints digital and analog inputs. Unfortunately, the arduino is running out of memory. To make the program smaller I'm trying to print the inputs using a for loop. I've been trying to do:

```
for(int analog = analog0; analog  <= analog9; analog ++){
  Serial.println(analog);
}
```

When I run the arduino, it doesn't always print out all of the inputs, sometimes it prints out none, or one or two, up to around 16 inputs (I only have 10 wired up). Each time this loop runs, it prints a different amount of inputs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about arduino, but if `analog0` is a reading of a analog value, then of course this code is not going to work. The value of `analog` is going to be a random ADC value!  Perhaps you need to do

```
for(int i = 0; i<= 9; i++){
   Serial.println(analogRead(i)); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't exactly work. I can't read the analog values like this, I must read them individually, and do some math to get the value the input represents (in my case pressure). If I try something like:
    `for(int i = 0; i<= 9; i++){
      Serial.println(analog(i)); 
    }`
Arduino thinks "analog" is a function.

Comment: His code is reading them individually. Look at what he wrote: analogRead(i). Look at what you wrote: analog(i).

Comment: You should post the rest of your code. How are `analog0` etc calculated or declared.  If you are calculating `analog0 = analogRead(0) * 3.3/4096` or something like that, you need to change your code to do `analog[0] = analogRead(0) * 3.3/4096`, and then the loop is over `analog[i]`.

Comment: I know, I have to read the analog values and do some math with their values to get a value for pressure (the inputs are from gauges). The gauges are all different so I have to read them, store them as analog0-analog9 and then print them like that. Mark's suggestion does work, but I can't use it in my program.

Comment: I don't know the exact calculations as of yet. For now I'm doing:
`int analog0 = analogRead(analogPin0);
    int analog1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
    int analog2 = analogRead(analogPin2);  
    int analog3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
    int analog4 = analogRead(analogPin4);
    int analog5 = analogRead(analogPin5);
    int analog6 = analogRead(analogPin6);
    int analog7 = analogRead(analogPin7);
    int analog8 = analogRead(analogPin8);
    int analog9 = analogRead(analogPin9);`

Comment: You don`t need to specify analogPin0, analogPin1, etc. Just 0,1,2, etc are just fine. This way you can store everything in an array. This is what Mark`s suggestion was going for.

Comment: If I try:
`int analog[0] = {analogRead(analogPin0)}`
it says "too may initializers for 'int [0]'"

Comment: You are creating a zero length array. try `int analog[1] = {analogRead(analogPin0)}`

Comment: `int analogArray[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    analogArray[i]=analogRead(i);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your for loop is incorrectly coded.

Also, try storing the analog ints outside of loop():

```
  int analog[10];

  // etc.

  loop() {
       int x;

      analog[0] = analogRead(analogPin0);
      analog[1] = analogRead(analogPin1);
      // etc. do calcs
      // for a beginning programmer, this for loop is OK
      for (idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
          serial.println(analog[idx]);
      }

}
```